# rails form_helper enable/disable textfield with radio button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

this should be straightforward but I can't seem to find a decent explanation/example. I am using form helper to build a model backed form. I have 2 radio buttons, if the first button is checked, i'd like a textfield disabled, if the second button is checked, i'd like the same textfield enabled. this is the code I have tried, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<%= f.radio_button :deposit_due_at_booking, true, :class => "deposit_due_at_booking_true", :onclick => "$('days_deposit').disable();"  %>Deposit due at time of booking</br>
<%= f.radio_button :deposit_due_at_booking, false, :class => "deposit_due_at_booking_false", :onclick => "$('days_deposit').enable();" %>Deposit due <%= f.text_field :days_deposit, :id =>"days_deposit", :disabled => true %> days after booking
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like just a minor syntax error in the selector you're using in the javascript.

Change: `$('days_deposit').enable();` to: `$('#days_deposit').enable();`

Comment: thanks! this mostly got it, and it got me on the right path, the other part was that .enable() wouldn't work, i had to call $('#days_deposit').prop('disabled', true) and $('#days_deposit').prop( 'disabled', false)